# change laravel mix extracted file path

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I have a laravel application and on that config the laravel mix like below

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
   .react('resources/assets/js/pages/treatments_pricing.jsx', 'public/assets/js/admin')
   .react('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/assets/js')
   .react('resources/assets/js/pages/channels.jsx', 'public/assets/js/admin')
   .react('resources/assets/js/pages/faq.jsx', 'public/assets/js/admin')
   .react('resources/assets/js/pages/threads.jsx', 'public/assets/js/admin')
   .js('resources/assets/js/component.js', 'public/assets/js/admin')
   .extract(['vue', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'react', 'axios']);
```

by default in documentation laravel said that the extract file path is `js/manifest.js` and `js/vendor.js`
I need to extract them to the `assets/js/manifest.js` and `assets/js/vendor.js`

but after compile the assets I can see laravel mix put the `vendor.js` and `manifest.js` to the 
`assets/js/admin/vendor.js` and `assets/js/manifest.js`.

how could it be happend?

and how should I change the path to the `assets/js`

Comment: take a look at [this fix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/224).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this yet but did you try `mix.setPublicPath('./assets/')`

I would also set that above your `mix.js` or `mix.reacrt` calls.